# bash string increase from vda to vdb in a loop

Tags: bash, string

I would like to increase a string by one, for example, from `vda` to `vdb`, from `vdb` to `vdc` and so on.

I was able to do it in one of the languages in the past by doing something like:

```
$c="vdb"+1
```

and

```
c == vdc
```

after that.

---

currently, I have a line which gets the last `vd*` disk from a VM:

```
current=$(virsh domblklist cic-1_vm | grep vd | awk '{print $1}' | sort -n | tail -n 1)
```

I want it to be added to `virsh disk-attach` command automatically as a target option, like this one:

```
virsh disk-attach $VM $DISK_FILE $DISK_NAME
```

SO I could do `$DISK_NAME` from `$current` automatically, without predefined case or smth...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
letter=${current#??}
letter=$( tr 'a-y' 'b-z' <<<"$letter" )

next="${current%?}$letter"
```

This first extracts the last letter of `$current` by deleting the first two characters.  It then uses `tr` to shift the letter to the next one in the alphabet.

At the end, `next` is assigned the first two characters of `$current` (the last one removed) and concatenates that with the shifted letter.

If `$current` is `vdc`, `$next` will be `vdd`.

Comment: I understand, but it will stop at when hits the last one... I do not know what the last will be: `current=$(virsh domblklist cic-1_vm | grep vd | awk '{print $1}' | sort -n | tail -n 1)` so I want to add to this a "next" disk

Comment: @BiG_NoBoDy See update. You question does not show that you know how many `vd` strings that you want to create, or what these string are, or any other background or context.

Comment: Ok, I'll update it in propper way.